# Dynamic parent element

Tags: haskell, reflex

I have this piece of code and it works perfectly fine. It toggles some styles on the text input field depending on the field value.

```
numberInput :: (MonadWidget t m) => m (Dynamic t (Maybe Double))
numberInput = divClass "form-group" $ do
  let errorState = "style" =: "border-color: red"
      validState = "style" =: "border-color: green"
  rec n <- textInput $ def & textInputConfig_inputType .~ "number"
                           & textInputConfig_initialValue .~ "0"
                           & textInputConfig_attributes .~ attrs
      let result = fmap (readMay . unpack) $ _textInput_value n
          attrs  = fmap (maybe errorState (const validState)) result
  return result
```

I ran into some problems making the parent element dynamic. I'd like to toggle the styles on the parent element of text input. I'd like to write something like but failed!

```
numberInput :: (MonadWidget t m) => m (Dynamic t (Maybe Double))
numberInput = do
  rec 
      dynAttrs <- -- reference to textInput
      elDynAttr "div" dynAttrs $ do
        n <- textInput $ def & textInputConfig_inputType .~ "number"
                       & textInputConfig_initialValue .~ "0"
        ...
```

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: What does 'failed' mean? A compiler error (include it *verbatim* and in *it's entirety) or a runtime error (describe it)? [You didn't post a complete program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it's nearly impossible for anyone to tell why your program doesn't work.

Comment: So 'failed' means that I would like to rewrite the working code of the numberInput function in a way that the dynamic attributes are set on the parent DOM node but I have only a very vague idea how that could work. I haven't grasped enough how reflect works  so I'm a bit lost on how to proceed and cannot provide any sample code or error message. But I have a very concrete question. How would you rewrite the perfectly good code that I provide in a way that the dynamic attributes are set on the parent DOM node.

Comment: "How would you rewrite this code to do X instead of Y" is off-topic for SO. I'm guessing you want to refer to `n` in the rhs of `dynAttrs`, but `n` is bound in the inner scope of the arguement passed to `elDynAttr`. The solution is probably to return `n` (and whichever other things you might need) from that inner scope, and bind those variables again in the outer scope: `do { dynAttrs <- .. n ..; (result, n) <- elDynAttr "div" dynAttrs $ do { n <- ..; .. ; return (result, n) }; return result }`. (I don't know enough about DOM to say for sure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little program where the attributes (align right or left) of the parent element depend on the state of a child element:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}
import Reflex.Dom
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Safe

main :: IO ()
main = mainWidget bodyElement 

bodyElement :: MonadWidget t m => m ()
bodyElement =  el "div" $ do
    el "h2" $ text "Dynamic parent element"
    numberInput
    return ()

numberInput :: (MonadWidget t m) => m (Dynamic t (Maybe Double))
numberInput =  do
    rec
       let errorState = ("align" :: T.Text) =: "right"
           validState = "align" =: "left"
       let result = fmap (readMay . T.unpack) $ _textInput_value n 
           attrs  = fmap (maybe errorState (const validState)) result
       n <- elDynAttr "div" attrs $ do
          n1 <- textInput $ def & textInputConfig_inputType .~ "number"
                                & textInputConfig_initialValue .~ "0"

          text "Some additional control"
          return n1
    return result
```

As user *user2407038* mentions, we have to return the numeric text element from an inner scope to the outer scope. Then we can use recursive do to access the element we define later in the program.

As soon as you type a letter into the numeric field, it will jump to the right.

Comment: user2407038's hint already helped me over the hump. Thanks for writing the solution down. I had to wrap my head around Recursive Do...